# are html5 data attributes case insensitive?

Tags: html

I recently noticed that chrome converts data attributes `data-*` to lower case.

**e.g.**

`<div data-Me="awesome"></div>` will be converted to `<div data-me="awesome"></div>` in Chrome Dev Tools.

When I call the attribute with javascript:

`console.log(e.hasAttribute('data-Me'),e.hasAttribute('data-me'));`

both return **true**.

So whats the standard way to name data attributes?

Comment: http://krangsquared.blogspot.com/2013/05/html5-custom-data-attributes-are-case.html http://xenforo.com/community/threads/html-5-data-attributes-and-case-sensitivity.15609/

Comment: Chrome is required to do that conversion by the HTML5 spec. All browsers with HTML5 compliant parsers must make that conversion. It is all quite normal and valid. The [HTML5 spec says](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/syntax.html#attributes-0) "In the HTML syntax, attribute names ... may be written with any mix of lower- and uppercase letters that are an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's name."

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should always use lowercase characters. Even though some browser do automatically correct mistakes in the markup (that's what Chrome does for you here) it can cause errors and isn't valid HTML5.
From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#data-*):

- the name must not start with xml, whatever case is used for these
  letters;
- the name must not contain any semicolon (U+003A);
- the name
  must not contain capital A to Z letters.

**EDIT**

After some more research I've found [this](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html#custom-data-attribute):

> All attribute names on HTML elements in HTML documents get
> ASCII-lowercased automatically, so the restriction on ASCII uppercase
> letters doesn't affect such documents.

Comment: If `<div data-Me="awesome"></div> ` is not HTML5 valid, why don't validators report it as an error?

Comment: @Alohci Because you shouldn't take the validator to serious (I guess you've used the W3C validator). It's not always up-to-date. Reading the official specs is always better.

Answer (score 16):

HTML5 tags and attributes ARE case INsensitive.

It makes no sense to get information from browser vendors. Instead, you should get that information directly from the source (W3C standards):
http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/documents.html#case-insensitivity

You can either use XHTML or HTML5. From a web page loading point of view only HTML5 makes sense currently.

> In documents in the HTML syntax:
>   • Tag names for HTML elements may be
>   written with any mix of lowercase and uppercase letters that are a
>   case-insensitive match for the names of the elements given in the HTML
>   elements section of this document; that is, tag names are
>   case-**insensitive**.
>   • Attribute names for HTML elements may be written
>   with any mix of lowercase and uppercase letters that are a
>   case-insensitive match for the names of the attributes given in the
>   HTML elements section of this document; that is, attribute names are
>   case-**insensitive**.