# Attribute selector in styled components

Tags: css, styled-components

I'm trying to use this syntax (using Emotion):

```
   .switch[data-isOn="true"] {
     justify-content: flex-end;
    }
```

Inside my styled component:

```
const Switch = styled('div')({
  cursor: 'pointer',
  ['data-ison'='true']: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
});
```

With no luck so far, how should I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the current selector using `&`, otherwise any nested selectors will be interpretated as child selectors.

You are in Javascript here.
`'data-ison'='true'` is an assignment that is evaluated to `true`.
so you Code actually means "assign the styles at the key `true`".

Also, you should always use lowercase data attributes, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25033330/2438494

Your styled components example in regular CSS would be:

```css
   .switch true {
     justify-content: flex-end;
    }
```

Try this instead:

```js
const Switch = styled('div')({
  cursor: 'pointer',
  ["&[data-ison='true']"]: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Should be:

```js
const Switch = styled.div`
  cursor: pointer;

  &[data-ison='true'] {
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
`
```

You can test this on the [editable example](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics):

[image]